# Lenovo laptop not recognising my bootable usb

Tags: dual-boot

So I want to install Windows 10. I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hwk0m_rewA0&t=888s, but instead of multisystem, I used WoeUSB. I made a bootable USB drive, but when I open the boot menu on my laptop, there is no USB. Does anyone know why?
I have a Lenovo V110 - 15ISK laptop.

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried every usb port?

Some laptops only will not boot off every port.